# TableView sections with Struct String in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am learning swift and I am hitting a wall. I am trying to automatically assign the components of a string to different sections in an UITableView.

I have A Struct :

```
struct Test {
            var name: String?
            var value: Float?
            var isfavorite:String? }

 var TestInformation = [String:Test]()
```

I then filled TestInformation with values so that I get a string that looks like this: `[Test(name: "Foo1", value: "1.32", isfavorite: "favorite"), Test(name: "Foo2", value: "1.27", isfavorite: "notfavorite")]`

I also have another array in which I put the section headers :

```
let actuallyfavorited: Array<AnyObject> = ["favorite","notfavorite"]
```

I can get `name` and `value` to be displayed in the table view fine but I can't figure out how to assign the cell to one of the two different sections based on whether of not the value of `isfavorite` is set to `favorite` or `notfavorite`.

I was hoping someone could point me to the right direction :)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use optionals only when you need them and that you have a boolean representing the state, then generate the sections by using functions to filter the elements from the list. Here is a basic example:

```
struct Test {
    let name:String
    let value: Float
    let isfavorite:Bool
}

func favorites(tests: [Test]) -> [Test] {
    return tests.filter{$0.isfavorite}
}

func hasFavorites(tests: [Test]) -> Bool {
    return tests.filter{$0.isfavorite}.count > 0
}

func nonFavorites(tests: [Test]) -> [Test] {
    return tests.filter{!$0.isfavorite}
}

let testInformation =  [
    Test(name: "Foo1", value: 1.32, isfavorite: true),
    Test(name: "Foo2", value: 1.27, isfavorite: false)]

let testInfoFiltered = favorites(testInformation)
```

**EDIT**

In case you are getting "Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'", please edit the code with these changes:

```
struct Test: Equatable {
    let name:String
    let value: Float
    let isfavorite:Bool
}

func ==(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.value == rhs.value && lhs.isfavorite == rhs.isfavorite
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, when I try this in playground I get an error `cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(_)-> _)'` for the three functions

Comment: Strange. It works for me: {name "Foo1", value 1.32000005245209, isfavorite true} is what I get from the testInfoFiltered list. What XCode/Swift versions are you using?

Comment: I added an edit that I hope will resolve your error for your specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to display favorite items in first section and other items in second section. I don't know what are keys in `TestInformation`, but things will be similar to the below codes.

Suppose `items` is an array of `struct Test`.
codes:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2 // You have two sections
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        /* The number of items that are "favorite'" */
        return items.filter({$0.isfavorite == "favorite"}).count 
    } else {
       // section 1
       /* The number of items that are "notfavorite" */
       return items.filter({$0.isfavorite == "notfavorite"}).count
    }
    return self.ratings.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let (section, row) = (indexPath.section, indexPath.row)
    if section == 0 {
         ....
         return .... // Your favorite item cell
    } else {
         ....
         return .... // Your 'notfavorite' item cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer. I am having trouble understanding this line: `return items.filter({$0.isfavorite == "favorite"}).count`. What do `items` and `filter` should refer to ?

Comment: items looks like [Test(name: "Foo1", value: "1.32", isfavorite: "favorite"), Test(name: "Foo2", value: "1.27", isfavorite: "notfavorite"), ...], `items.filter({$0.isfavorite == "favorite"})` is just 'filtering' only favorite items. It's also an array that only contains 'favorite' items in `items`. Therefore, the whole expression means 'the number of favorite items in `itmes`'

Comment: Thank you, but I still get an error `[String : ViewController.Test]' does not have a member named 'filter' ` ... :(